Inlined function C++ debugging
When I debug and type some value in evaluate expression box. I got this error "Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined". Could anyone can tell me how can I do evaluate some object properties in evaluate expression box.
Hug thanks!
I have searched all page related to this problem and all of them tell that it's impossible because GBD compiler optimization feature. But I want to ask all of you once more.
Here is my C++ code:
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    stack<int> the_stack = stack<int>({1, 2, 3});
    return 0;
}

In my example, how can I type "the_stack.size()" or "the_stack.top()" in evaluate expression box then I get the expected value.
My build command config:
       {
      "label": "build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": ["-O0", "${file}", "-g", "-o", "${workspaceFolder}/build/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
}


Compile on -O0 with -g flag, you should have all variables shown.

@TedLyngmo thanks, I 've updated my post, is my build command correct ? I added "-O0" flag but it seem nothing changed.

If you compile manually so that you are sure that you are debugging the debug compiled binary, does that work? What is the_stack? Perhaps you should show a [mre] of your code too.

@TedLyngmo yes, I compile my file manually to .exe file then use gdb, my build command is "g++ -O0 .\stack.cpp -g -o stack" (stack.cpp is the name of c++ code of my pos). When I press "p the_stack.top() ", result in gbd console is "Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined". Is my build command correct ?

If the program never uses the_stack.top(), then the function was probably not compiled into the executable, so you also can't evaluate it with gdb.

@ssbssa, I've never heard about it. Do you mean I must declare a var like int  top = the_stack.top() ? I 've worked with js, ts file, I can easily access object's properties, regardless whether those properties were declared separatedly or not.

@Nobody_left_behind Member variables is one thing. Unused member functions in classes based on class templates is another. Especially when the compiler can see that they are unused.

You are not using the_stack.size() in your code and the_stack is an instance based on a template, so the member functions you're not using will most probably not exist in the binary.
Just try return the_stack.size(); instead of return 0; (just to use the member function) and then run the debugger and do p the_stack.size(); after stepping over the initialization.
Possible output:
Reading symbols from stack...
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at stack.cpp:5
5           stack<int> the_stack = stack<int>({1, 2, 3});
(gdb) p the_stack.size()
$1 = 18446744073643061723
(gdb) n
6           return the_stack.size();
(gdb) p the_stack.size()
$2 = 3
(gdb)

You could force the instantiation of the std::stack<int> class early to generate the member functions. It's not very nice for production code, but perhaps you'll find it useful:
#include <stack>

template class std::stack<int>; // explicit instantiation

int main()
{
    std::stack<int> the_stack = std::stack<int>({1, 2, 3});
    return 0;
}

Note that this only instantiates std::stack<int>. If you later add std::stack<double>, it'll have to be explicitly instantiated too in order for the unused member functions to become available.

Without explicitly instantiating std::stack<int>, you could instead use one of the Xmethods defined for std::deque.
(gdb) info xmethod
...
  libstdc++::deque
    empty
    size
    front
    back
    operator[]
    at
...

In order to use one of these methods, you'll have to lookup (p the_stack. + tab + tab) the name of the member variable in the std::stack implementation you are using. In my implementation it's c, so:
(gdb) p the_stack.        (tab + tab)
c       empty   pop     push    size    stack   swap    top     ~stack
(gdb) p the_stack.c
$4 = std::deque with 3 elements = {1, 2, 3}
(gdb) p the_stack.c.size()
$2 = 3


hmm, it seems not as convenient as js or ts debugger. Is there any possible approach to easily access object's properties that weren't declared ? In my example is "the_stack.top()"

@Nobody_left_behind It's rarely a problem. In your mini example, there is no need to have access to these member functions. When you actually start using your stack for something in your code, you'll have access to the function you've used. Even without using the member functions, you could just p the_stack and get $3 = std::stack wrapping: std::deque with 3 elements = {1, 2, 3}

@Nobody_left_behind Re: "Is there any possible approach to easily access object's properties that weren't declared ?" - I added a possible workaround.

Agreed, I realize that my example is too much simple. In real case, I must write those object's properties once or more. It's such a feature, not a bug. Thanks for your help.

Note that stack is implemented on top of deque, and since there are gdb xmethods available for deque, you can do p the_stack.c.size() and p the_stack.c.top(), and it just works. Now I wonder why there aren't xmethods also for stack, but maybe they just didn't bother.

@ssbssa That's very nice and I didn't know about that. I tried searching for a good place to learn about the built-in Xmethods and what class templates they've covered, but I couldn't really find a good place. Any pointers? I'd like to add it to the answer.

The easiest way to see the available xmethods it just enter info xmethod in gdb.

@ssbssa I got the list of the Xmethods and I get that c accesses the deque but what is c refered to as? "container"? Is it always c? Is there anything more than c? Sorry for the many questions but I've never used Xmethods :-) Need to find a good man-page.

c has nothing to do with xmethods. If you look at the implementation of stack here, you see that there is a c member of type deque.

@ssbssa Ah... Ok, so one has to look at the implementation of the thing. Seems reasonable. Many thanks! I will take some time and then add this info to the answer.

"reasonable" is probably debatable. It would be more user-friendly if there were xmethods also for stack available.

@ssbssa Sure, I meant in general, it's reasonable to go via the member variable if there is no ready Xmethod. Anyway, I've added a little something about the Xmethods to the answer.

@Nobody_left_behind Btw, did the answer answer your question or is there anything you'd like me to clarify?

@TedLyngmo yes, it's clear enough. Thanks for your answer. My problem start from a too naive thought. I realize that: if you don't mention a property in your code, I don't need it when debugging, too.

@TedLyngmo ahh, yep, because this is the first time I raised a question. I don't even know that I can accept this answer, I thought that a bot will do it automatically. Yeah, thanks for your answer again
